# Android My APK size Larger 50 MB

Tags: android

am developing a game app.,it contains more number of images,music files etc., it exceeded more than 50MB.but as per  playstore , Market will allow on 50MB of apk size,plz provide me any solution to upload apk with more then 50MB of size,

Thank in advance....

Comment: The Play Store allows you to upload an additional APK.

Comment: remove unwanted files.. make it below 50mb

Comment: I have seen many Apps that you download it from Google Play and then it provides you a link to download the media data

Answer (score 4):

Try apk expansion files:
http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/expansion-files.html

Answer (score 2):

```
to decrease the apk size you can do following things Like

1) Don't keep the any unnecessary file in the build ,

2) If images are of High definition decrease their density 
  or use smaller images  where you could use

3 ) Decrease the size of sound files by decreasing its bit rate

4) or what you can do is keep the resources to a server and download  them when are about to used.
```

and see this link also

http://developer.sonymobile.com/wp/2012/01/31/tips-for-reducing-apk-file-size/

Answer (score 0):

Play Store supports extension files for your APK's, (in the form of 2 obb files which can be up to 2GB each) you can download them in your main app
See here: [APK Extension files](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/expansion-files.html)

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a late answer, but it may help others who encounter a similar issue:

**As of recently** (Sept. 2015)**, you are able to upload APKs up to 100 MB** if you are targeting Android 2.3 and above - you can read more about it [on this help page](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2481797?hl=en-GB). This limit used to be 50 MB. There is also the Android developers blogspot article explaining the changes [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2015/09/support-for-100mb-apks-on-google-play.html).

Alternatively, or if your app exceeds the 100 MB APK limit, you can use **expansion files**. These are additional files that are downloaded after your app has installed and can be up to 4 GB (to be specific, you can have two expansion files of up to 2 GB each). You can learn more about expansion files on [this page on the Android Developers website](http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html).

However, note that there are some limitations to using expansion files, apart from the 2 GB limit per file such as the fact that the user must have downloaded your app through Google Play. More details on these can also be found on the Android Developers page linked above.